# Is model checking PSpace-hard *in formula size*?

Tags: complexity-theory, model-checking, linear-temporal-logic, parameterized-complexity

Sistla/Clarke proved [[SC82](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/emc/papers/Papers%20In%20Refereed%20Journals/The%20complexity%20of%20propositional%20linear%20temporal%20logics85.pdf)] that the LTL model-checking problem is PSpace-complete.
Sometimes people write that this problem is "PSpace-hard **in $|\phi|$**" (e.g. [[LP85](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.467.2053&rep=rep1&type=pdf)]). What does this mean formally?

How to prove that a decision problem that has several parameters (here, $\phi$ and system) is PSpace-hard in one of the parameters? I guess we would need to poly-time reduce some PSpace-complete problem to our problem *with the unintereseting parameter being fixed*, while the interesting parameter can vary.

But the original proof of Sistla/Clarke [Lemma 4.4, [SC82](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/emc/papers/Papers%20In%20Refereed%20Journals/The%20complexity%20of%20propositional%20linear%20temporal%20logics85.pdf)] does not do the thing above! In their proof, both parameters of the resulting LTL model-checking problem instance depend on $n$, where $n$ is the TM tape bound. Is there a proof that fixes one of the parameters?

Comment: Your question inspired me to ask https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106877/ltl-and-alternation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are certainly right that the level of rigor found in old papers making such claims can be a bit low at times when viewed from today's perspective.

The claim is correct anyway, even if it does not follow from Sistla/Clarke's proof. The reason is that LTL satisfiability checking is also PSPACE-complete. You can see satisfiability checking as a special case of model checking.

More formally, you want to prove the following: There exists a fixed model such that given an LTL formula, checking if the formula holds on the model is PSPACE-hard. Now the satisfiability checking problem does not restrict the number of atomic propositions, so a fixed model does not do the trick. However, S. Demri and P. Schnoebelen show in the paper "The complexity of propositional linear temporal logics in simple cases" (Inf. Comput., 174(1):84–103, 2002) that the satisfiability problem is hard even if we only have a single atomic proposition.